# Can't get the current text in alert box in react native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, camera, state, qr-code

I am building a React native QR code and barcode scanner application where i had created a button which on pressed scan the qr code and display it on alert box and in a text view. But I am facing a difficulty in alert box it display the previously set text in alert box rather than the newly scanned qr text.

App.js

```
import { BarCodeScanner } from "expo-barcode-scanner";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View, Linking, Alert } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null); //check for permission
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false); //checks ifs scanned or not
  const [text, setText] = useState("Not yet scanned"); //set the text var

  //define camera permission
  const askForCameraPermission = () => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === "granted");
    })(); //here it is a promise so we have to write a () at the end
  };

  //call Camera Permission
  useEffect(() => {
    askForCameraPermission();
  }, []);

  //what happened when we try to scan the bar code
  //type-> Scanner type Barcode / QR
  //data->actual data scanned
  const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    setScanned(true);
    setText(data);
    console.log("Type: " + type + "\nData: " + data);
  };
  //Check permission and return screens

  //INitial view while asking permission
  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  //view when permission is denied
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{ margin: 10 }}>No access to Camera</Text>
        <Button title="Allow Access" onPress={askForCameraPermission} />
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  //view when the permission is granted
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.barcodeBox}>
        <BarCodeScanner
          onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
          style={{ height: 400, width: 400 }}
        />
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.mainText}>{text}</Text>
      <Button
        title={"Scan again?"}
        onPress={() => {
          setScanned(false);
          showAlert({text});
        }}
        color="tomato"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  barcodeBox: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    overflow: "hidden",
    borderRadius: 30,
    backgroundColor: "tomato",
  },
  mainText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    margin: 20,
  },
});
```

Comment: Its because the entirety of onPress is executed on the same render. It will call for scanned to be set to false and pass the current value of  text  to showAlert. It doesnt wait for scanned being set to false to trigger the whole update process. So instead, you should call showAlert in `handleBarCodeScanned` and something like `showAlert({text:data})`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @PhantomSpooks my issue got resolved